# iAd status: Showing live ads but no ads are showing?

Tags: ios, iphone, iad

I had an app approved and submitted to the app store today, and downloaded it on my phone (because why not) and no ads are appearing where I had called them. The iAd network was working perfectly fine during development showing all the test ads in the proper places, but no live ads are being showed on my device. Is this a problem? Does anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Give it a day or two, but you should also know that iAds is only going to last until June 30th https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=01152016a

Comment: Oh wow, thanks a bunch for this. I'll definitely be switching networks in the near future.